# Example of two subrings with unity of a ring with unity whose intersection is non trivial and has no unity.

Tags: ring-theory, rngs

I was just thinking about the intersection of rings and this question popped up, I tried giving an example and proving that the intersection had to have an unity, but was unsuccessful in both.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you also said your question outside of your title.

Comment: If $R$ is a ring with unity, and $S$ is a subring with unity then, by definition, the unity of $S$ is the unity of $R$. So what you are asking for, does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edit: As Gerry suggests, it's pedagogically wise to explain that the definition of 'subrings with unity' almost universally requires that the unit element in the ring is also the unit element of the subring. In that case, there is a unique unit element in any subring, and the intersection of any set of subrings will, by definition, contain that unit element.

I took the question to be asking about the weaker definition of subrings (a subset which is itself a ring - i.e. closed under the ring operations) which as individual rings have their own unit elements.

In other words, why do we require 'subrings' to contain the ring's unique unit element? What subrings (in the weaker sense) that have their own individual unit elements have an intersection without a unit element?

---

Take $A$ to be the continuous functions from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. The unit element here is the constant function $f(x) \equiv 1$.

$B$ is the set of (all) functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $f(0)=0$. The unit element here is 
$$1_B(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 0 & \text{if } x=0 \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$$

If $h$ is in $A\cap B$ and is not identically 0 then there is some value $x\in \mathbb R$ for which $h(x) \not\in \{0,1\}$. Then $h^2 \not= h$ so $h$ is not the identity in $A\cap B$.

Comment: Of what ring-with-unity are $A$ and $B$ both subrings?

Comment: The ring of *all* functions from $\mathbb{R}$ into itself?

Comment: @Jens, $1_B(x)$ is not an identity in that ring.

Comment: $1_B$ is the identity in $B$ only.

Comment: Then $B$ is not a subring-with-unity of the ring-with-unity of all functions from $\bf R$ to itself.

Comment: The definition of a subring often requires it to have a unit and for that unit to be the same as the one in the ring. With that definition, the answer to this is trivially 'no'. You can also define rings without requiring a unit. In that sense these are subrings and they happen to have unit elements but their intersection has none.

Comment: Yes, but the question specifically says "subrings with unity of a ring with unity," and I interpret that to mean we are in the case given in the first sentence of your comment, gregory.